# With CFRelease Memory not decreasing/released with 5000 contacts in AB

Tags: ios

- I have 5154 contacts.
- When I launch app, the memory grows to 300MB
- In Xcode, then it stays there even if app goes to bg & fg multiple times
- Without executing the code, memory stays at 70MB

Why is CFRelease not releasing all the memory? Whats is wrong? Or is this expected?

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
    CFIndex nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(allPeople);
    for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
        NSArray *expandedList = [self getExpandedContactsFromABRecordRef:person];
        // do some work

    }
    if (allPeople != NULL) {
        CFRelease(allPeople);
    }
    if (source != NULL) {
        CFRelease(source);
    }
    if (addressBook != NULL) {
        CFRelease(addressBook);
    }


- (NSArray *)getExpandedContactsFromABRecordRef:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSMutableArray *expandedContacts = [NSMutableArray new];
    CFStringRef firstNameRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    CFStringRef lastNameRef  = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)firstNameRef;
    NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString*)lastNameRef;

    ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);i++) {
        CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
        NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
    }
    if (multiPhones != NULL) {
        CFRelease(multiPhones);
    }
    return expandedContacts;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**my bad - this is wrong - CoreFoundation was a while back..dont release it**

(not deleted so op sees it)

you don't release the contacts you get with `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex` - ergo you leak a lot of contacts

Comment: @user2384694 please show me the line you wrote and where :)

Comment: my bad - this is wrong - CoreFoundation was a while back..dont release it

Answer (score 0):

Code above is correct. The issue was somewhere else in a third party lib.

Please ignore the question above.